# Payload with multiple properties values in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, payload, mutation

I have this demo: https://codepen.io/Albvadi/pen/abdVZxO

I want pass in the payload the title and the class, but only the class is read...

If I change the `@click` event to pass an object, the JS don´t compile:

```
// Compiles but dont work
<button
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    @click="addComponent('primary', 'My Title')"
>PrimaryAlert</button>
```

```
// No compile
<button
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    @click="addComponent({'primary', 'My Title'})"
>PrimaryAlert</button>
```

error compilation

```
Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token ',' in

    addComponent({'primary', 'My Title'})

  Raw expression: @click="addComponent({'primary', 'My Title'})"


19 |                          <div class="row">
20 |                              <div class="col">
21 |                                  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addComponent({'primary', 'My Title'})">Primary
   |                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
22 |                                      Alert</button>
23 |                                  <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="addComponent('warning')">Warning
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `{'primary', 'My Title'}` is not valid JavaScript syntax. Are you trying to create an object? What should the keys be?

Comment: The mutation expects `classAlert` and `title`, alogn with the `state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send one payload data to the mutations from the parameter, so if you need to send multiple data, you need to send an object instead, change your `@click` to:

```js
@click="addComponent({classAlert: 'primary', title: 'My Title'})"

@click="addComponent({classAlert: 'warning'})"

@click="addComponent({classAlert: 'danger'})"

@click="addComponent({classAlert: 'dark'})"
```

and your mutations parameter to:

```js
// destructuring the parameter
addComponent(state, { classAlert, title }) {
  console.log(classAlert);
  console.log(title);
}

// not destructed version
addComponent(state, data) {

   const classAlert = data.classAlert;
   const title = data.title;

   console.log(classAlert);
   console.log(title);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/vincentjonathan99/pen/vYLWXeR

Comment: Great, thank you!! One question more: it's a must using the keys, can't be less verbose? Why if I have two vars named `classAlert` and `title` I can write `addComponent({classAlert, title})` without the keys?

Comment: Yes you have to provide the keys, if you are initializing object with variable without key, the key automatically will be set to the variable name (its called shorthand property names), so `{classAlert, title}` is the same with `{classAlert: classAlert, title:title}`, and if you need different keys, you can do `{alert: classAlert, otherTitle: title}`, read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Understood! Thank so much for your explanations!!